# How to configure Static IP to centos without using HWADDR field in network script

Tags: centos, ip

I want to set static ip to CentOS machine so i have done changes to script file */etc/sysconfig/network-script/ifcfg-eth0* as

```
DEVICE=eth0 
BOOTPROTO=static 
STARTMODE=onboot 
IPADDR=10.100.200.59 
ONBOOT=yes 
NETMASK=255.255.0.0 
GATEWAY=10.100.0.1 
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

I dont want to specify the HW_ADDR field in script file and also remove 70-persistent-net.rules.I rebooted the system,it doesn't come up with static it comes up with dhcp ip. Whenever I ran the command `sudo ifup eth0`, it gets the satic IP..

PLease help me out for this problem I want to set the static ip in *network-script/ifcfg-eth0* without using HW_ADDR and without running command `sudo ifup eth0` manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this as your network script:

```
DEVICE=eth0 
BOOTPROTO=none  
IPADDR=10.100.200.59 
ONBOOT=yes 
NETMASK=255.255.0.0 
GATEWAY=10.100.0.1 
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

I took out your STARTMODE parameter as you already have ONBOOT configured and changed your BOOTPROTO to none.

Comment: Hi i have tried as you suggested but no luck its still showing me the dhcp IP

Comment: You say that it will work if you use the ifup script.  Perhaps you have something else misconfigured.  Try using "ip addr" to verify you are using the correct interface and all scripts are named correctly.  Also, if you do a "systemctl restart network" does it get a DHCP address or does it pull the static address?